# "Beggars in Spain" - what does the title mean?

Tags: nancy-kress, beggars-in-spain

In the novel by Nancy Kress, what does the title '[Beggars in Spain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_in_Spain)' mean? English is not my first language, so I suppose I am missing something here. I understand the basic idea behind the title, but the exact choice of words puzzles me.

Is "beggars in Spain" a common phrase in English, or it is something specific to the book?

Comment: I wondered this question once too, unfortunately because wikipedia answers this question it may cause the community to close the question.

Comment: I found this series very disturbing...  But I read them all.

Comment: I disagree that Wikipedia answer the question. It answer the meaning of the sentence, but not if the sentence is chosen because it is a "common place" in English language or a specific creation for the book.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the link you provided:

> The novel's title comes from its
>   primary moral question, as presented
>   by character Tony Indivino: **what do
>   productive and responsible members of
>   society owe the "beggars in Spain,"
>   the unproductive masses who have
>   nothing to offer except need?** This is
>   only underscored by the rift between
>   Sleepers and Sleepless; Sleepless are
>   superior in mind and body, and easily
>   capable of outperforming their normal
>   cousins. All men are not created
>   equal. Where, then, is the line
>   between equality and excellence? How
>   far should any superior minority hold
>   themselves back for fear of
>   engendering feelings of inadequacy in
>   their inferiors?—especially if this
>   minority is not hated and feared, but
>   rather the elite? This question is
>   explored, but not elaborated on by the
>   novel.

The point is not that the beggars are in "Spain" but merely: "do we owe the poor and the unfortunate anything?".  Spain is just an arbitrary other location used in the original quote where the author got the title from.

It's not an English expression if I remember correctly.

Comment: OK, so Spain is chosen arbitrarily as an example of remote place in order to highlight that "responsible members of society" are not relate to them in any way. Also, "beggars in Spain" is a sentence original from this book and not an Anglo-Saxon expression. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: While it might not be the cause of choosing "Spain", I remember reading in more than one work of literature, that a certain type of beggar was referred to as Spaniard, even if he was not. Spain was a very rich country in the 16th/17th centuries, but after losing its dominance in the New World, it became bankrupt. This led to a lot of noblemen becoming poor, but they were still very proud, and some of them became beggars who were loudly offended if someone refused to give them what they requested. This might fit the image of someone who behaves as if others had a "duty" of giving them alms.

Comment: @vsz thanks for your answer, I though it could be something like this. If you remember where you read it I would like to know. Anyway, maybe, this question only can be definitely solved by the author ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is definitely NOT a common phrase in English, most people would have absolutely no clue what you were talking about if you were to say it out loud.

This title is actually explained in detail in the book itself:

> "What if you walk down a street in Spain and a hundred beggars each want a dollar and you say no and they have nothing to trade you but they're so rotten with anger about what you have that they knock you down and grab it and then beat you out of sheer envy and despair?"
>
> Leisha didn't answer.
>
> "Are you going to say that's not a human scenario, Leisha? That it never happens?"
>
> "It happens," Leisha said evenly. "But not all that often."
>
> "Bullshit. Read more history. Read more *newspapers*. But the point is: What do you owe the beggars then? What does a good Yagaiist who believes in mutually beneficial contracts do with people who have nothing to trade and can only take?"
>
> "You're not --"
>
> "*What*, Leisha? In the most objective terms you can manage, what do we owe the grasping and nonproductive needy?"
>
> "What I said originally. Kindness. Compassion."
>
> "Even if they don't trade it back? Why?"
>
> "Because..." She stopped.
>
> "Why? Why do law-abiding and productive human beings owe anything to those who neither produce very much nor abide by just laws? What philosophical or economic or spiritual justification is there for owing them anything? Be as honest as I know you are."
>
> Leisha put her head between her knees. The question gaped beneath her, but she didn't try to evade it. "I don't know. I just know we do."

Answer (score 1):

https://books.google.com/books?id=qY4eAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=origin+of+the+phrase+beggars+in+spain&source=bl&ots=2ftMR7Kd3m&sig=_9tNWkKLP843s9xP-7IwkGe4hGs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFxL7-7tPNAhXJ6YMKHS6bBd44ChDoAQhCMAg#v=onepage&q=origin%20of%20the%20phrase%20beggars%20in%20spain&f=false

In the 1500s, many places in Spain passed laws trying to register "legitimate" beggars, recognizing that charity was not natural to their newly urbanizing populace (particularly after ejecting their Muslim and Jewish population, although this book doesn't make that point).  These laws were the first attempt to distinguish between the "deserving poor" and the "undeserving poor" in western society.

I honestly do think it was the crisis of ejecting the Jews and Muslims from their society that precipitated this, as a side note.  Those cultures enforce alms giving, where it's highly optional to give directly to the needy in Christianity.  You give to the church and the state as intermediaries.  So in the decades in Spain after the expulsion, I imagine they were overwhelmed.

This was always my assumption for where the name came from as the question of deserving and undeserving comes up frequently.  The question of those who demand or those who are in desperate straits and left stranded by the circumstances and decisions made far beyond their control are central to the story.

But of course, you'd have to be a very geeky history nut who cared about such problems of history as something of a social engineer, wouldn't you? Oh, wait...:)

For myself I never got around to writing F&SF, I just lived it...

Comment: How does this answer the question of whether "beggars in Spain" is a common phrase in English, or something specific to this book?

Comment: It isn't a common phrase in English as far as I know.  I've never heard it as such.  It is, as others had commented, from historic events, which I elaborated on.